# yarn deploy sets gh-pages to static create-react-app page instead of what is on my branch

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, package.json

I have deployed my app at `https://hudsonbasso.com/` and it is just showing the readme instead of what is showing on my branch when run locally. I suspect is something with the build folder or gh-pages not recognizing my index.js in the src folder. Link to repo https://github.com/hbasso/wherecaniwatch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwXE8.png)

Comment: Change the subdirectory in your repo settings [in the same place as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580095/gh-pages-page-is-showing-blank-page) and add a [nojekyll file](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/).

Comment: So the new root of the gh-pages branch should be the build directory? Or I am just one directory to high in my repo? So I think what I currently have is this @ZacAnger

```
wherecaniwatch
  - build
  -public
  -src
package.json
index.js
yarn.lock
```

Comment: I think I'll try deleting my github pages branch and trying this https://jiafulow.github.io/blog/2020/07/09/create-gh-pages-branch-in-existing-repo/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by adding a .nojekyll file and following some of the instructions here https://jiafulow.github.io/blog/2020/07/09/create-gh-pages-branch-in-existing-repo/ to create an empty branch called 'gh-pages' and then my `yarn deploy` worked!